# How to make a (matrix?) transformation permanently a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, transformation, matrix-transform

I'm currently working with a `RecyclerView` which has an horizontal `LinearLayout`. The `RecyclerView` occupies all the screen:

[image]

and I'm finding the way to make a fix transformation of the `RecyclerView` like this:

[image]

note that the transformation is like a "sinking" or "downfall" to make a "deep" effect. Since the items' size can change, I need a permanent transformation, that's why I'm thinking to make it in the `RecyclerView`

Is there anyway to do it? maybe a way to do it on `onDraw` ??

Thank you very much in advance.

Regards.

Rafael.

---

**ADD**:

I'd like to notice that [`PageTransformer`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html) does something similar. In fact, the thing that I want is very similar of what Samsung Galaxy S3 makes when you scroll with one of their Launchers (which uses `ViewPager`), but I'd like to make that transformation fixed:

[image]

---

**WHAT AM I TRYING?**

I'm trying to scroll a large horizontal adapter of `RecyclerView`, but I'd like to "fold" a little bit the view to make a little impression of "cylinder".

Comment: you were close in your question title: make a class that extends `RecyclerView` and override its `dispatchDraw` method, use `Matrix#setPolyToPoly` to make perspective transformation

Comment: of course you would need to call `setPolyToPoly` twice, unless you are the "Matrix expert" (like Mr Anderson ;)) and know how to flip it and translate

Comment: Hi @pskink that's definitely the solution, but I can't get how to do it since there's not much documentation of those practices... could you be more specific, maybe via answer and I will validate it ? (Thank you very much)

Comment: you have problems with `dispatchDraw` or `polyToPoly` ?

Comment: Since I've never done that, I don't know how to start, I've tried to export this example and work with it, but I wasn't able: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/2D-Graphics/DrawPolygon.htm

Comment: see [here](http://pastebin.com/QJUf6XEc)

Comment: I understand now... if you write an answer I will check as valid!! thank you very much !!

Comment: doesn't seem finally what I was looking since the final result is a disaster :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a class that extends `RecyclerView` and override its `dispatchDraw` (or `draw`) method, use `Matrix#setPolyToPoly` to make perspective transformation, the below code makes something like  "Star Wars" effect, you would need to call `setPolyToPoly` twice and apply the `Matrix` on both halves of your custom view:

```
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        final float DELTAX = w * 0.15f;
        float[] src = {
                0, 0, w, 0, w, h, 0, h
        };
        float[] dst = {
                0, 0, w, 0, w - DELTAX, h, DELTAX, h
        };
        matrix.setPolyToPoly(src, 0, dst, 0, 4);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.concat(matrix);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
```

Comment: just one thing.. any idea of how to do it twice ?

Comment: make two `Matrices`, call `setPolyToPoly` twice, and finally   apply those `Marices` twice, each time setting the correct clipping on the `Canvas`

Comment: Sorry, didn't find the way... I want to make 2 transformations to make the figure above... I'm doing in this way, but not getting the result at all: http://pastebin.com/f6mKNzbu

but dont worry about that, I'll figure out

Comment: I'm mathematician hehehehe. I know how to make it theorically (I split the layout in two and I apply my transformations to each one: http://pastebin.com/f6mKNzbu) but doesn't seem to work together

Comment: if you are mathematician, so maybe you will tell me what is difference between `Matrix#pre*` and `Matrix#post*` methods? just in simple words? not in that math jargon...

Comment: hehehe if a preconcats the b, then matrix a = b×a... if a postconcats b, then a = a×b...., where × stands for matrix multiplication, not scalar multiplication. Math is not my problem, my problem is that I'm trying to put in practice my math into android and I can't get it done.... this is how I do it, for example, in GIMP (by using matrices): http://oi68.tinypic.com/qqpqg9.jpg

Comment: And... obviously, × is not commutative, so that's why there are 2 methods.

Comment: yes, doesn't work, but with this new thing with two matrices I'll try to tweak it.... let's hope it will work... I'm going to accept it anyway. Thank you

Comment: it works, vertically, i tested that on ListView which is vertical, just exchange x <-> y

Comment: in fact that's what I'm doing right now... Thank you very much for helping... I really appreciate it... did you study math as well?

Comment: ooops my code is here, i linked your code by accident, http://pastebin.com/KgP8GVuK, btw the second Matrix, can it be made by simply scale the first by (-1, 1) ??? this is a good question for you ... ;-)

Comment: I don't think so, it's a shear, not a rotation matrix... is that your question ? I didn't understand it very well :D

Comment: ok, see my code, i compute 2 matrices, and the second is a mirror of the first (since there are two symmetrical trapezoids) so my question is if i can compute the second matrix based on the first (i just made a test that proves that i cannot be done but i dont know why...., my bad math...)

Comment: If you want to see the result, I've got the math... this is the real video (scrolling, plain, normal...): https://media.giphy.com/media/poXqCl7331qDu/giphy.gif and this is the result applying the math :D https://media.giphy.com/media/YcoFn4klZTDVu/giphy.gif

the code I've done is:

http://pastebin.com/eiqkSc6m

Comment: code looks ok, but... the the result gif is imho wrong as it always shows one half only, is it what you wanted?

Comment: no :), just a light transformation to make it "fold"

Comment: also I've tried the "replace" with `UNION`, `REPLACE` and `XOR`